# Incompatible type error with IntelliJ. The stock method takes an int and a double. What am I missing here?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, types

See the purchase method below where the error occurs
public class StockMain {

```
public static void main (String[] args){

    Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

    // first stock

    System.out.println("First stock symbol:");
    String symbol1 = console.next();
    Stock stock1 = new Stock (symbol1);
    System.out.println("How much shares do you want to purchase?");
    int units = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println(" What is the price per share?");
    double shareprice = console.nextDouble();
    double profit1 = stock1.purchase(units,shareprice);

}
```

}

Comment: please share snippet of purchase function as well

Comment: What return type does the method have?

Comment: post full printstacktrace

Comment: I just saw the error actually. The method returned nothing and I was assigning it to a variable.

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw the error actually. The method returned nothing and I was assigning it to a variable.

```
public class Stock {

    // This class represents a common stock on the market.

    private String symbol;
    private int totalShares;
    private double totalCost;

    // constructors begin here
    // pre: Stock != null

    public Stock (String theSymbol){
        // initialise stock with no shares purchased
        if (theSymbol == null) throw new NullPointerException();

        symbol = theSymbol;
        totalShares = 0;
        totalCost = 0.0;
    }


    // methods begin here

    public double getProfit(double currentPrice){

        // return the total price of the stock.

        if (currentPrice < 0 ) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        return totalShares * currentPrice - totalCost;
    }

    public void purchase (int shares, double pricePerShare){

        // records the purchase units and prices of shares
        if (pricePerShare < 0 || shares < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        totalShares += shares;
        totalCost += pricePerShare * shares;

    }

    public String getSymbol(){
        return symbol;
    }
}
```